# Rails Display Messages Sorted by Timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails, I have a "Messages" class each with a timestamp that records when the message was sent. (created_at)

I'd like to display all of these messages in a div tag, sorted by timestamp with a loop such as:

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
```

I'm not sure how to make this sort them by their created_at timestamp, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply query these `@messages` and order them by `created_at` attribute:

```
# controller:
@messages = Message.order("created_at DESC").all
```

However, if you feel that you would like to it in the controller, it would be:

```
# controller:
@messages = Message.all.sort_by(&:created_at)
```

Bear in mind that `sort_by` chained to `all` is a bad combination since you're handling more data than what's needed. Prefer the QueryMethods methods ActiveRecords provide for that.